# ¿Como setear el boton Imprimir del Vista previa para imprimir directo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, print, jobs

tengo la siguiente función que imprime para generar vista previa:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#imprime").on('click', function (ev) {
            CallPrint();
            clickimprime();
        });
    });
    function CallPrint() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('main1');
        var newWin = window.open('width=100,height=100', '_blank');
        newWin.focus();
        newWin.document.open();
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.innerHTML);
        newWin.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () { newWin.close(); }, 10);
    }
    function clickimprime() {
        $("button.print").click();
    }
</script>
```

Pero lo que yo deseo, que cuando se abra el vista previa, se haga click automaticamente el boton imprimir, llamando a la función clickimprime.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me gustaría saber como podría gatillar ese boton para que haga click. Les agradecería su ayuda, desde ya, gracias.

Comment: (Creo) que eso no es posible... y espero que no se pueda ya que seria un problema grave de seguridad... es para una red privada o pública?

Comment: Comparto lo de @aldanux , pero quizás algunas de las alternativas que ofrece google en sus API te pueda ayudar, más abajo dejé un link que habla al respecto, pero no sé si te sea de gran ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Al igual que @aldanux creo que no es posible manipular eso, de ser posible podría volverse un problema grave en materia de seguridad

Comment: El truco sería tener una página 'imprimir.html' donde tenga el código js que necesites ejecutar `$('button.print').click()` y uses `window.open('html2.html')`

Comment: @Yikarus, de hecho como se ve en la pregunta, eso estaba intentado de hacer, pero no resulta